# Summing up a column of numbers for each unique item in another column

Tags: file-io, awk, sed

I have a file in Linux. For each unique title in the first column, I must sum up the values of all the fourth columns that have the title in their first column, and just output those two columns in the end. For instance:

```
AF116642    792 t   1   ^!. ]
AF116642    793 g   2   .   ]
AF116643    794 t   5   .   ]
AF116643    795 g   6   .   ]
AF116643    796 t   3   .   ]
AF116644    797 g   1   .   ]
AF116644    798 t   8   .   ]
AF116644    799 g   1   .   ]
```

would ideally produce:

```
AF116642   3
AF116643   14
AF116644   10
```

Same names in the first column of the input file are consecutive, and their order should *not* be switched in the output file. I only have pieces of sed and awk knowledge, and cannot piece them all together to perform this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data in a file called `books,` the numbers for each book can be added and printed them as follows:

```
$ awk '{n[$1]+=$4} END{for (b in n) {print b,n[b]}}' books
AF116642 3
AF116643 14
AF116644 10
```

In the above code, `n` is an associative array.  The keys are the book names.  Every time that we encounter a line, the number in the fourth column, denoted `$4`, is added to the total for its book, `n[$1]` where `$1` is the name of the book in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the order you can do:

```
awk '
$1!=prev && NR>1 {
    print prev, sum;
    sum = 0;
}
{
    prev = $1;
    sum += $4
}
END {
    print prev,sum
}' file
AF116642 3
AF116643 14
AF116644 10
```

- We create a variable `prev` and assign it the value of column 1 and another variable `sum` to which we add column 4.
- If column 1 does not match to `prev` variable and line number is greater than 1, we print the variable and sum and reset sum to 0.
- In the `END` block we print that last known value of our variables.

**Note:** Using associative arrays is good but it **does not** preserve the order of output. Since you have stated that first column in your file are consecutive, this approach will work.